# Android thread confusion

Tags: java, android

I have written a function to create a splash screen with a 5 second timeout for my app.

The code works fine, but when the timeout reaches zero and I want to redirect to my main activity, the app crashes with the following error:

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

So I looked around a bit and someone suggested nesting this inside my function. It seems like a good Idea, but now methods like sleep / stop won't work.

My code is below, I can provide more / explain more in details if it isn't clear enough just let me know. Thanks for the help.

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        showSplashScreen();

    }

    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 5000;  // Splash screen is 5 seconds

    public void showSplashScreen() {

        setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);

//      Thread splashThread = new Thread() {

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

             @Override
             public void run() {
                 try {
                     int waited = 0;
                     while (_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                         Thread.sleep(100);
                         if (_active) {
                             waited += 100;
                         }
                     }
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     // do nothing
                 } finally {
                     showApplication();
                 }
             }
         });
    }
```

Comment: Note that the stop function in the Java thread class has been deprecated. Any new code shouldn't try to use it.

Comment: Why showSplashScreen() calls it self in finally block? For what is this recursion?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I modfied the code a bit, now it seems to work ( splash screen for 5 seconds than main activity ) but my splash screen is all black...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will perform sleep on the UI thread. That's never a good idea.

Why not something like this?

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // start application ...
    }
}, _splashTime);
```

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854034/android-thread-confusion/7854115#7854115) has a good point. Displaying a splash screen for 5 seconds can be very annoying.

Comment: chosen best answer for actually trying to help me resolve the problem... thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Probably not what you want to hear, but you should never put a splash screen on your mobile app. With the exception of games, when people use a mobile app they want to get in, do what ever it is they need to do, and get out. If you make that process take longer, people are just going to get frustrated with you app. You should probably reconsider just not using a splash screen.

Comment: `With the exception of games` Games are no exception imo. Unless you're actively loading data/legitimately not ready to display the main activity.

Comment: Oh yea, games shouldn't have splash screens either. I was trying to say that most apps are used for like 30 seconds at the most where as games might be used for like minutes or hours.

Comment: I don't decide the design specifications... sadly.

Comment: @JFFF Here's what you do: You go back to that design team and say "HEY! This is stupid! We're gonna piss off our users! We're not doing it!". Then mumble something about how you've got a new name for your .50 caliber, and storm out of the room. They'll think you've gone postal or something and never question any of your design changes again. You'll now be free to remove the splash screen...and occasionally steal peoples lunches and get away with it.

Comment: This has to be the best comment I have ever recieved on this website... by far.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** for this.  The method called on completion of the task will be called on your UI thread, making modifying UI elements much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Handler to post an event to the UI thread that will remove the splash.

Code should be something like...

```
   splash.show()
   new Handler().postDelayed(
      new Runnable() {
          void run() {
              splash.remove();
          },
      delayTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make new activity for your spalsh screen, show it in a regular way (with startActivityForResult) and place in it such code (in it, not in your main activity):

```
new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable()
  {
  public void run()
    { finish(); }
  }, 5000 );
```

Also you can handle in this new activity click events for giving opportunity to user to close it faster, tapping on it.